# Calculating a bunch of results in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for some insight. Artistic creativity and data is more my strong point and not so much math.

Say I have an mmo style text based browser game that I'm messing around with. The level system is potentially unlimited but as people go up in level it will become harder and harder to reach the next level. What I want is for it to start out rather easy. I'll set a base target amount of experience points required to reach level 2. But here's where my problem comes in. I'd like to know what some viable options are for setting the levels going forward. My thoughts were to make a script that I run one time at the creation of the game. It would start with:

```
$base_xp = 100;
```

This would be the amount of experience points required to reach level two. Then for every level after that I just want each level to increase by a percentage of the level before it. Perhaps 3 or 5% more than the previous level. The script would run, with

```
i=1;
```

and then run a foreach look or while loop and insert into database a table that lists every single level and it's experience point requirement maybe to something like level 1,000 for now.

To me that seems really tedious. But so does manually typing in

```
$level2 = 100;
$level3 = 205
$level4 = 310;
```

etc etc.. for possibly thousands of levels.

The only other thing I can think of is a math formula that runs every script execution to see if they've met the requirements for the next level. But I'm a little fuzzy on how to write such a formula being kinda bad at math and all.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. If i had to make a definitive question it would be:

**What is an efficient way to dynamically or statically create a list of levels and their xp requirements?**

If I do make an SQL table for it and insert them all. i could just query it once and store those requirements with APC or something else, to make retrieval faster during game play and not query the database every time for a table with a thousand or more rows.

Comment: this might be a question better suited on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Augwa this math is not so complex that it needs to be migrated to math.se

Comment: if your table is properly indexed it won't be that tedious of a query. just a thought, but if when you level up you have a preset number you can just do the number of the amount you're at * .03 add to the number you're at and set that as the next level cap

Comment: So what you're saying is. make a $next_level type variable starting at level one. and maybe a single field in my character row like next_level. and when I hit level two just take the current experience points multiplied by .03 (or whichever percentage points) then add the original to it.. and then insert the result as next_level into the database and just target one level at a time? I suppose that would work well. Especially if level 2 is a base requirement then I can still have a list somewhere that generates to list what each level requirements are..but that list need not run every run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a two ideas. The first was my comment.

You have a stored number in your game that is always the number at which you increase the cap by. I would do something `greater than 3%` so it can be super hard later. But I would say `maybe 6% being the cap`. I'm not going to say that is much greater, but if others can provide a better number than that would be fine. This way when the value hits your `CAP` you do `CAP = CAP * x + CAP` and now you have your increased cap. No queries..

However, what if you want to tell someone you can get to level 50 at X. Or level 1000, 10000000000. You may want a table for those instances. In that case I would create a loop of that just stores into a database that has an auto incremented ID and store the XP expected. You will need to determine datatype for the XP but maybe int won't be good enough.

```
$cap = 100;
for($i = 0;$i < 10000000;$i++){
    $cap = $cap * $i + $cap
    // insert data
}
```

Then yea. When you query do their current level and then go up to the next 5 levels so you can keep a running number of XP possibilities. Or query them all you're call. At some point memory will run out.

I would maybe consider only doing up to level 100 until someone gets to level 50 then go to 200, 300 so on so forth until you are satisfied with your game level cap. Always stopping the person from reaching 201 if there is only a cap of 200.

Comment: if you do the running level cap as people get closer it will give a sense of the game updating constantly which may encourage longer game play.

Comment: this is what I was thinking too. And I think it's the best idea.. just giving it some thought.. it wouldn't be that bad of a query at all. Because I'm really only every looking ahead one level at a time. So even if i run a query every script execution to check if the level has been met. Really I can do one single query by doing $currentlevel + 1 = $indexlevel then do an sql query like SELECT FROM xp_table WHERE next_level = $indexlevel. does that make sense to you?

Comment: yepp that would work very well AGAIN proper indexing of a table is what you need. If you don't have index 3 and check for 3 then no one will ever make it to 3.

Comment: like @Mike said do something exponential for level amount. like 4% of cap ^ 2 which could grow much faster

Comment: Alright, I will do an exponential that makes much more sense. I can see now a base percentage is far too small. I will create a table and just execute a single script one time to populate it up to like maybe level 2500 or something. honestly I will adjust the math numbers so that it will be very improbable to pass level 1,000 even after a year of obsessive game play.. i just want to future proof as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to generate the number of points needed for the next level, and each next level is just 4% (for example, as you mentioned) higher than the next? Don't store anything, just calculate it:

```
<?php

function check_level($lvl) {
  $percent_increase = 0.04;
  $ret = 100;

  if ($lvl == 1)
      return 0;

  for ($i=3; $i <= $lvl; $i++)
      $ret = $ret + ($ret * $percent_increase);

  return $ret;

}

for( $x=1; $x <= 20; $x++)
  echo "$x: ".check_level($x).PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Output:

```
1: 0
2: 100
3: 104
4: 108.16
5: 112.4864
6: 116.985856
7: 121.66529024
8: 126.5319018496
9: 131.59317792358
10: 136.85690504053
11: 142.33118124215
12: 148.02442849183
13: 153.94540563151
14: 160.10322185677
15: 166.50735073104
16: 173.16764476028
17: 180.09435055069
18: 187.29812457272
19: 194.79004955563
20: 202.58165153785
```

This increases slowly at 4% though. Might want to use something larger, or more likely, something exponential

Comment: didn't even try the math. DIdn't notice how small it was. something exponential would be much better.

Comment: That or even a simple multiplier. Each level is twice the amount as the last, triple, however sadistic you want to be.

Comment: yes I will have to adjust the math. What I'll probably do is add the last level's xp plus a small percentage. so if level 2 required 100 points, i'd probably make level 3 require 200 points + 5% something along those lines. Thank you both for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Really the only thing that matters is that the number goes up. Maybe the rate could even be configurable - "easy mode" uses a simpler percentage, "hard mode" increases exponentially, that kind of thing. Like I said, however sadistic you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

In case it can ever help anyone in the future.. here is the conclusion I came to.

```
$level = $currentlevel;
$nextlevel = $level+1;

$cap = 50;
for($i = $level;$i < $nextlevel;$i++){

$percent = 8;
$percentage = $percent / 100;
$sum1 = $percentage * $cap;
$sum2 = $sum1 + $cap;

$sum3 = $sum2 * $i;
echo "level $i: $sum3<br>";
}
```

I did not actually wind up storing anything in a database. I'm just going to go with dynamic generation. The formula above only calculates the next level ahead. But I also made the following formula based on Cayce's and Mike's recommendations that can generate a list of any number of infinite amount of levels. The below example would show up to level 1,000 and the xp requirements.

```
$cap = 50;
for($i = 2;$i < 1001;$i++){

$percent = 8;
$percentage = $percent / 100;
$sum1 = $percentage * $cap;
$sum2 = $sum1 + $cap;

$sum3 = $sum2 * $i;
echo "level $i: $sum3<br>";
}

Example Output:

level 2: 108
level 3: 162
level 4: 216
level 5: 270
level 6: 324
level 7: 378
level 8: 432
level 9: 486
level 10: 540
level 11: 594
level 12: 648
level 13: 702
level 14: 756
level 15: 810
level 16: 864
level 17: 918
level 18: 972
level 19: 1026
level 20: 1080
```

Just so that it makes sense. The amount of xp required seems small between each level, but as you level up your xp is wiped and you have to attain the entire amount of xp listed for that level, not just the difference between say level 3 and level 2.